# Sending Email based on name in a cell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I have looked through multiple posts to send an email if a value in a range of cells changes and adapted the code I found in those posts to suit my needs, but for some reason the email is not being sent when the value in any cell of the range defined changes, and I am a little lost at why.  Any guidance is greatly appreciated.  Please see code below (please note that for confidentiality purposes the emails and names are fake).

```
Private Sub Workbook_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'   Uses early binding
'   Requires a reference to the Outlook Object Library
    Dim RgSel As Range, RgCell As Range
    Dim OutlookApp As Object, MItem As Object
    Dim Subj As String, EmailAddr As String, Recipient As String
    Dim CustName As String, Msg As String
    Dim pEmail As String

    On Error GoTo NX

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Set RgCell = Range("C2:C100")
    Set RgSel = Intersect(Target, RgCell)

    If Not RgSel Is Nothing Then
        Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set MItem = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)
            For Each cell In RgCell
                If cell.Value = "Bob" Then                      'Fake Name for posting question
                    pEmail = "BobT@SomethingBlahBlahBlah.com"   'Fake email address used for posting question
                    CustName = cell.Offset(0, -1).Value
                    Subj = "***NEW ITEM ASSIGNED***" & " - " & UCase(CustName)
                    Recipient = "Bob T. Builder"                'Fake name for posting question
                    EmailAddr = pEmail

                '   Compose Message
                    Msg = "Dear, " & Recipient & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
                    Msg = Msg & "I have assigned " & CustName & "'s" & " item to you." & vbCrLf
                    Msg = Msg & "Please review the information in their customer folder in the L: Drive." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
                    Msg = Msg & "Sincerely," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
                    Msg = Msg & "Bob's Boss" & vbCrLf           'Fake name for posting question
                    Msg = Msg & "Vice President"

                '   Create Mail Item and send
                    With MItem
                        .to = EmailAddr
                        .Subject = Subj
                        .body = Msg
                        .Save   'This will change to .send after testing is complete
                    End With
                    Set RgSel = Nothing
                    Set OutlookApp = Nothing
                    Set MItem = Nothing
                End If

            Next cell
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

NX:
    Resume Next
End Sub
```

Comment: `Workbook_Change` or `Worksheet_Change`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change Also, you shouldn't `Set OutlookApp = Nothing` within your `For Each` loop, but outside it. Are you missing a closing `End If` as well, or is it just not included in this snippet?

Comment: Thank you @BigBen sorry it should be Worksheet_Change and i have taken out the Set OutlookApp = Nothing from the loop.  I definitely need more caffeine this morning :).  Also i noticed that CustName Reference is grabbing the info from the last cell with "Bob"  in the RgCell range when i thought it would grab the value from the cell in Column B that was adjacent to the cell that went from null to "BoB".  Would you have any guidance on that issue as well?

Comment: If you want `custName` to reference the cell in column B that is adjacent to a cell in column C with the value of "Bob", then `Offset` is the way to go. Also, did you mean to loop `For Each cell In RgCell` or `For Each cell in RgSel` (which btw, not sure why you have `Set RgSel = Nothing` within the loop either).

Comment: I changed RgCell to RgSel and it now works as expected and I removed the three lines that  set values to =Nothing.  Also please forgive my ignorance in designating code items in comments as I am still learning how everything works  in here.  Thank you again @BigBen for your guidance and assistance.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: @ZackE Welcome Zack - for future reference, no need to make comments saying how you've redacted the real information - that's very common around here and none of us would ever expect you (or anyone) to use the real emails/information. In fact, sometimes we'll remove it purposefully to maintain user confidentiality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've intended to use the [`Worksheet_Change`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change) event but have `Private Sub Workbook_Change...` instead.

Additional issues:

- `For Each cell In RgCell` should probably be `For Each cell in RgSel`, or `For Each cell in Target` - otherwise the code runs through each cell in `C2:C100`, and not just the cell(s) changed, or `Target`.
- There is no need to `Set RgSel = Nothing`
- With `Set MItem = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)`, you create an email message *before* you've checked `If cell.Value = "Bob"`. Move this line *within* the `If` statement.
- `Set OutlookApp = Nothing` should be *outside* the `For Each` loop, i.e. it should be done *after* you've finished looping.
- `On Error GoTo NX`, and then `NX: Resume Next`, is equivalent to `On Error Resume Next`, which doesn't handle any errors, but rather ignores them.
- You may be missing a closing `End If`, or it is not included in this snippet.